# Restricting issue creation of certain types based on user project role / group

Tags: jira

I was wondering if there is a way to restrict creation of an issue type based on which role or group the creator is in.

For example, I want only Developers to be able to create a "new feature" or "enhancement" but not "story point". I have tried the permission scheme already.

Is that possible?

Comment: You haven't stated which Jira version you are using and whether it is hosted by you or cloud based. The newest version of Jira doesn't seem to have this ability per-se but there is a hack described here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/161095/restricting-issue-creation-of-certain-types-based-on-user-project-role-group

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by adding conditions to your workflow.
On the create transition you can put a condition saying which roles are needed to be able to create a certain issuetype.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not hide the issue type from list, this will prevent to submit the ticket, if user does not belong from the project role.

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured you meant with restrict. To hide the actual issueType based on project role you could try to use Livefields:
https://confluence.kepler-rominfo.com/display/JJUPIN/How+'Live+Fields'+work
However this does require a plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can try JavaScript approach. Add the Script in Create Screen. Check user membership of Group/Role through AJAX call. Then Enable/Disable Issue type in Create Issue Drop Down.

```
function getCurrentUserName()
{
    var user;
    AJS.$.ajax({
        url: contextPath +  "/rest/gadget/1.0/currentUser",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            user = data.username;
        }
    });

    return user;
}


function getGroups(user)
{
    var groups;
    AJS.$.ajax({
        url: contextPath + "/rest/api/2/user?username="+user+"&expand=groups",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            groups = data.groups.items;
        }
    });
    return groups;
}
function isUserInGroup(user, group){
    var groups = getGroups(user);
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
        if (groups[i].name == group){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```